# JQuery UI sortable: drag and drop element to non-list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

My list is sortable, and that's all well and good. What I want to do now is be able to drag one of those sortable `li` elements and drop it onto some other `div`. I know I can make that other div a `ul` and use the `connectWith` feature, but I'd rather not do that in this case.

I've also tried using `draggable` on the same `li` elements, but when I do that, they are no longer sortable.

How can I have my sortable `li` elements be dragged to anther specific non-`ul` div?

Answer (score 0):

As in the docs from jQuery UI stated:

> By default, sortable items share draggable properties.

So you can use your sortable list to drop it at a `droppable`.
When using a list for your `sortable` you are sorting and dragging `li` elemtents which obviously cannot be append to something else then a `ul` or `ol`, so one solution could be extracting the content of that elemtent and append it seperatly.

You can use the [drop](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop) method of `droppable` and access the `ui.draggable` inside:

```
$("#sortable").sortable();

$("#droppable").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
  var $sortEl = $('<div>').html(ui.draggable.html());
    $(this).append($sortEl);
  }
});
```

---

**[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ovukb8rg/)**